# PL/pgSQL iterating through returned type

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have a stored procedure such as the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.sp_shared_asset_delete_by_id(
    "in_shared_asset_id" bigint,
    "in_client_uuid" uuid)
  RETURNS boolean AS
$BODY$
declare
"participant" cursor
begin
      "participant" is select * from get_all_participants("in_shared_asset_id");
      FOR row in "participant"
      LOOP
        --DELETE EACH PARTICIPANT
        sp_participant_delete_by_id(row.participant_id, row.created_by_client);
      END LOOP;
  return true;
end
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE SECURITY DEFINER
  COST 100;
```

get_all_participants("in_shared_asset_id") returns a setof "participant" records.

What is the correct way to iterate through all of the records returned from the get_all_participants call? Currently, I am getting a plsql error "near" begin.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.get_all_partipants(in_shared_id bigint)
  RETURNS SETOF participant AS
$BODY$
begin
  return query select participant.participant_id,
                      participant.shared_asset_id,
                      participant.participant_role_type,
                      participant.user_external_ref_uuid,
                      participant.user_first_name ,
                      participant.user_last_name ,
                      participant.user_email_address,
                      shared_asset.asset_external_ref_uuid uuid,
                      shared_asset.owner_external_ref_uuid uuid,
                      participant.deleted_timestamp
               from participant
               join shared_asset
               on shared_asset.shared_asset_id = participant.shared_asset_id
               where shared_asset.shared_asset_id = "in_shared_id"
               and participant.deleted_timestamp is null;

end
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE SECURITY DEFINER
  COST 100
  ROWS 1000;
```

Comment: This does not even look like pl/sql.

Comment: What is the **exact** error message that you get?

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need a cursor but your plsql syntax look quite strange. Just keep it simple.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.sp_shared_asset_delete_by_id(
"in_shared_asset_id" bigint, "in_client_uuid" uuid) 
RETURNS boolean IS
DECLARE
  row participant%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN

  FOR row IN(SELECT * FROM get_all_participants("in_shared_asset_id"))
  LOOP
    --DELETE EACH PARTICIPANT
    sp_participant_delete_by_id(row.participant_id, row.created_by_client);
  END LOOP;
  RETURN TRUE;

END;
/
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and I get the following                                            Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: loop variable of loop over rows must be a record or row variable or list of scalar variables. What does this mean ?

Comment: Hi @XnaijaZ , it means that your function  get_all_participants("in_shared_asset_id") doesn't really return a set of records as you stated. Can you double check the return type or provide the details of that function?

Comment: I believe you are using PSQL syntax not PLSQL ?

Comment: Hi @Nexus I have added the function above. Still do not understand why I am getting the error.

Comment: First of all, you test this query alone: SELECT * FROM get_all_participants("in_shared_asset_id") . See if it data is correct. If yes, you might try to play around with DECLARE row participant%ROWTYPE; or DECLARE row RECORD;

Answer (score 0):

The cursor definition is wrong. It should be ended with a `;`

To *use* the cursor you need [`OPEN`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-cursors.html#PLPGSQL-CURSOR-OPENING) it.

The syntax `"participant" is select *...` is wrong (where in the manual did you find *that*)

You also did not declare the record variable holding the row returned by the cursor. You can simplify that by not using an explicit cursor variable and simply [loop over the query result](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-RECORDS-ITERATING)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.sp_shared_asset_delete_by_id(
    "in_shared_asset_id" bigint,
    "in_client_uuid" uuid)
  RETURNS boolean AS
$BODY$
declare
  l_rec record;
begin
      "participant" is ;
      FOR l_rec in select * from get_all_participants("in_shared_asset_id")
      LOOP
        --DELETE EACH PARTICIPANT
        perform sp_participant_delete_by_id(l_rec.participant_id, l_rec.created_by_client);
      END LOOP;
  return true;
end
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE SECURITY DEFINER
  COST 100;
```

---

Unrelated, but: `get_all_partipants(in_shared_id bigint)` can be simplified to a plain SQL function. No PL/pgSQL needed there.